# Qt - Segfault on QDrag exec

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, segmentation-fault

I am currently working on a project with Qt 4.8.5 and c++.

I created a custom Widget called ItemView and i reimplemented the methods for drag and drop.
Problem is, it segfaults on QDrag::exec().
So i tried to compile in debug mode and now it works.

Here is the code :

```
  std::pair<AItem const *, unsigned int>    *pair = new std::pair<AItem const *, unsigned int>(_item, _nb);
  std::ostringstream       oss;

  oss << pair;
  QDrag         *dr = new QDrag(this);
  QMimeData             *data = new QMimeData;

  data->setText(oss.str().c_str());
  dr->setMimeData(data);
  dr->exec();
```

And here is backtrace

```
#0  0x00007ffff4b33c6a in strlen () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7adc425 in XSetCommand () from /usr/lib/libX11.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7ae0831 in XSetWMProperties () from /usr/lib/libX11.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff5cc9a07 in QWidgetPrivate::create_sys(unsigned long, bool, bool) () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#4  0x00007ffff5c8142d in QWidget::create(unsigned long, bool, bool) () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#5  0x00007ffff5c8997a in QWidget::setVisible(bool) () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#6  0x00007ffff5cc0bcf in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#7  0x00007ffff5cc1e15 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#8  0x00007ffff5c4c064 in QDrag::start(QFlags<Qt::DropAction>) () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#9  0x000000000041d8da in ItemView::makeDrag (this=0x2e31db0) at src/Qt/Views/ItemView.cpp:155
#10 0x000000000041d9c3 in ItemView::mousePressEvent (this=0x2e31db0, mEvent=0x0) at src/Qt/Views/ItemView.cpp:66
#11 0x00007ffff5c8a4a1 in QWidget::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#12 0x00007ffff5c3b0dc in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#13 0x00007ffff5c417dd in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#14 0x00007ffff570bebd in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#15 0x00007ffff5c40f93 in QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent(QWidget*, QMouseEvent*, QWidget*, QWidget*, QWidget**, QPointer<QWidget>&, bool) () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#16 0x00007ffff5cb2bab in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#17 0x00007ffff5cb161c in QApplication::x11ProcessEvent(_XEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#18 0x00007ffff5cd8162 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#19 0x00007ffff2f4a296 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007ffff2f4a5e8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#21 0x00007ffff2f4a68c in g_main_context_iteration () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#22 0x00007ffff5738b25 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#23 0x00007ffff5cd8216 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#24 0x00007ffff570ab1f in QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#25 0x00007ffff570ae15 in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#26 0x00007ffff570ff4b in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#27 0x000000000042b041 in WindowManager::exec (this=this@entry=0x733b90) at src/Qt/WindowManager.cpp:66
#28 0x00000000004401c0 in Client::init (this=this@entry=0x729750, ac=ac@entry=1, av=av@entry=0x7fffffffe858) at src/Client.cpp:52
#29 0x0000000000414b04 in main (ac=1, av=0x7fffffffe858) at src/main.cpp:22
```

Is there a way to make this work in release mode too ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the solution. I don't create the QApplication in my main so I had to pass argc by reference in the functions where i do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
data->setText(oss.str().c_str());
```

will [construct a new QString possibly backed by](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#QString-8) a `char*` from a ***temporary string*** (ie destructed for sure after returning from setText). Later when your program will try to manipulate the string it will crashes on release (because it is invalid), but may not on debug, because of the compiler shenanigans.

Rather uses

```
data->setText(QString::fromStdString(oss.str()));
```

Comment: While this recommendation is correct, the original code is not problematic and is not the source of the crash. There is no such thing as a "QString possibly backed by a char*". `QString(const char*)` does a deep copy of the argument and it's fine to pass temporary strings to it.

Comment: I tried you're solution but it doesn't work. In fact, it doesn't even work with `data->setText("test");`. Any other idea ?